# How can I batch-copy pages from one Wordpress directory to another on the same domain?

Tags: wordpress, plugins, web, copy

I have a directory type site in which I have thousands of pages advertising local businesses. I wish to duplicate those pages under another directory.

So for example, say I was pursuing a keyword of 'guitar strings' with thousands of vendors under the directory http://my-site.com/guitarstrings/'1000's_of_vendor_pages'.

I now wish to go after the keyword 'guitar straps' and so I create a new directory or parent page http://my-site.com/guitarstraps/'1000's_of_vendor_pages_copied_here'.

Don't worry about duplicate content as I have a trick for that.

However, it WOULD be useful if in some instances I could batch change some item or items on the new pages to suit the new keyword so if anybody knows how to do this that would be great.

Can anybody help? Try and keep the answer as non-technical as you can. :-)

Comment: *Can anybody help? Try and keep the answer as non-technical as you can.* Sorry, this site is for specific programming questions. Being non-technical here is almost impossible.